# jquery .load function running more than once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement SEO friendly infinite scrolling in accordance with google's recommendations as seen here (http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=7). I have a jquery function that sends a request to a php file, (which requests the data from the db) anytime someone scrolls to the bottom of the page, now everything is working fine except that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the request function gets fired more than once. So duplicate entries of the data gets loaded into the page, now i know this isn't from my php file because i opened the page directly in my browser and everything was fine. Checkout the bug here http://devx.dx.am/haze/categor.php?artemis=foo&&page=1

I have already tried the solutions here ([jQuery .load() callback function fires multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489422/jquery-load-callback-function-fires-multiple-times)) and here ([$(window).load() is executing 2 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783542/window-load-is-executing-2-times)) and a few others as well.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() { //#cagorwrap is the div that should contain the data retrieved
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#cagorwrap').offset().top + $('#cagorwrap').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) { //344.6
      var queryParameters = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
      while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
          queryParameters[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
      }
      var url2 = "modules/paginate.php?numpages=set";
 // #rc is a hidden div too
      $("#rc").load(url2, function() {
        var rc = $(this).html();
        if (queryParameters['page'] < rc) {
          queryParameters['page']++;
          console.log(rc);
          var stateObj = queryParameters['page'];
          let cagh = $('#cagorwrap').height() + 344.6 - 75;
          $("#cagorwrap").height(cagh);
          history.pushState(null, null, "categor.php?artemis=cat&&page="+stateObj);
          var url = "modules/paginate.php?artemis=cats&&page="+stateObj;
          $("#obtainer").load(url, function () {
            $("#cagorwrap").append($(this).html());
          }); //#obtainer is a hidden div that receives the data at first before it is appended to #cagorwrap
        } else{
          //unbind scroll here
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: You're calling `$("#rc").load(url2, function() {` etc in a "scroll" callback. This means that every time the scroll event handler gets called you're adding a new `load` event handler. That's why it's firing multiple times.

Comment: Ok that pointed out something to work on, i suspected this at first but ignored... it's working now. marry me :)

Answer (score 1):

well if all else fails and you absolutely need a solution, you can add a 
`counter=1;` on the start 
and only fire the request function in the case below

```
  counter++;
    if (counter%2==0){//fire request}
```

It's not clean, but if you're loosing too much time with this and want to return to the problem later on...